# How do I prevent the Alexa simulator from having to reinvoke my skill using "open (invocation word)" after the first question?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

Could not find any current questions that solve my problem.

I am using the nodejs-howto sample from alexa tutorial.  Located https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-howto.

I have followed the instructions for the Alexa-Hosted and was successful in creating the app.

I am using the alea simulator for testing via typing in the questions.

Problem: After asking the first question which does return the correct response. I then ask another question but the simulator seems to have closed my skill and the question is sent to the default alexa where of course my question does not exist.  I have to re-invoke the skill after the first question.

My code is copy and pasted from the instruction from the above github link.

Thanks.

Comment: There are two things to check, to make sure that you are not closing the session after your response.
1. Is there a reprompt prompt?
2. Are you not setting flag 'shouldEndSession' to true
You can find both of these properties in your lambda response. If they are there then there is something else probably. In this case, try to share more of your code or response that you send to alexa. For more complete tutorial, how to build skills, you can check amazon's 'Cake walk' skill tutorial: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/courses/cake-walk-1

Comment: `I then ask another question` - How are you asking the second question?

Comment: R. Vait -- I did not have a reprompt. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your session is getting closed after the first response. Make sure that your intent response sets shouldEndSession as false

> **shouldEndSession**
>
> A boolean value that indicates what should happen after Alexa speaks
> the response:
>
> true: The session ends.
>
> false: Alexa opens the microphone for a few
> seconds to listen for the user's response. When you use false, include
> a reprompt to give the user a second chance to respond.
>
> null / undefined: Behavior depends on the type of device and the content of
> the response. See Keep the Session Open.

EDIT : As per @R.Vait and @dan comments

Check whether a re-prompt is used and is properly configured.

Comment: This is also true, however in my case it was using a reprompt prompt as suggested in the comments above by  R. Vait